# Empty Pod Headers Folder after `pod install`

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

My AppName -> Targets -> Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Header Search Paths is set to: `"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public"`

When I run pod install and get:

```
$ pod install

Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Alamofire (3.1.1)
Using AlamofireImage (2.1.0)
Using DateTools (1.7.0)
Using JGProgressHUD (1.3.1)
Using Locksmith (2.0.8)
Using SwiftyJSON (2.3.1)
Using TPKeyboardAvoiding (1.2.10)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 7 dependencies from the Podfile and 7 total pods installed.
```

But, my Headers directory is still empty.

The exact errors I am having can be seen in my earlier question which has been answered but without really solving the problem, just making me realize that my question was wrong: [How do I tell my app where my Pod header files are?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579484/how-do-i-tell-my-app-where-my-pod-header-files-are/37580187#37580187)

**EDIT 1**

I have tried some workarounds such as the tactic in this question: [Framework did not have a CFBundleIdentifier in its Info.plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601925/framework-did-not-have-a-cfbundleidentifier-in-its-info-plist) that I asked, but it just seems to kick the can down the road

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ gem uninstall cocoapods
$ gem install cocoapods
```

Add all things (crashlytics and fabric included) as pods

```
$ pod install
```

See this Question for more info: 
[Framework did not have a CFBundleIdentifier in its Info.plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601925/framework-did-not-have-a-cfbundleidentifier-in-its-info-plist)