# Framework did not have a CFBundleIdentifier in its Info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I was having issues with my Bridge.h imports finding their intended targets after a cocoapods install and run.

I had:

```
#import <TPKeyboardAvoiding/TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.h>
#import <DateTools/DateTools.h>
```

But it didnt work because my Headers folder was empty, so I copied those two folder into the Headers folder and hardcoded the path:

```
#import </Users/username/Documents/new_ios/ios-app/Pods/Headers/TPKeyboardAvoiding/TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.h>
#import </Users/username/Documents/new_ios/ios-app/Pods/Headers/DateTools/DateTools.h>
```

This worked and the app built but when I ran it it gave this error: `The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)`

Here is the console output:

```
6/2/16 4:41:24.961 PM uploadDSYM[3519]: Fabric.framework/run 1.4.0
6/2/16 4:41:24.981 PM uploadDSYM[3521]: Fabric.framework/run 1.4.0
6/2/16 4:41:25.011 PM appleeventsd[51]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22
6/2/16 4:41:25.019 PM sharedfilelistd[251]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22
6/2/16 4:41:25.093 PM Fabric[257]: Bundle indentifier is of type (null), returning empty string.
6/2/16 4:41:25.752 PM com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[331]: Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={Error=MissingBundleIdentifier, ErrorDescription=Bundle at path /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/#####-####-####-####-##########/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.16rUWf/extracted/AppName.app/Frameworks/TPKeyboardAvoiding.framework did not have a CFBundleIdentifier in its Info.plist}
```

The initiall error that I have looks alot like this stuff: [Unable to run app in Simulator: An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889189/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain) I tried all the clean builds and the reboots suggested but none worked. Also all the sharekit solutions also did not work because I do not have sharekit.

**EDIT 1**

My guess is this: `Frameworks/TPKeyboardAvoiding.framework did not have a CFBundleIdentifier in its Info.plist}` is the real problem and I need to change my info.plist file to find TPKeyboardAvoiding

**EDIT 2**

My info.plist:

[image]

**EDIT 3**

This question is a problem that arose after I tried to workaround the problem which I ran into before which is described in this question: [Empty Pod Headers Folder after `pod install`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37581039/empty-pod-headers-folder-after-pod-install)

Comment: I've been strugling with similar issue. Take a look at answer on similar question: [Unable to run app in Simulator: An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39049990/923642)

Comment: I was able to solve this with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39049990/4564088 but I think my problem wasn't 100 % identical.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

For me cleaning the build folder worked. In Xcode, hold `alt` Product -> Clean Build Folder..

Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Worked for me! Wonder what that primary difference is between cleaning the build folder and just cleaning the project... google might know.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it was the solution for me. I'd like to invite you as @justColbs mentioned to describe what's the difference between the default clean and the cleaning the build folder.

Comment: @justColbs [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087065/xcode-4-clean-vs-clean-build-folder) is what are we looking for :)

Comment: Worked 4 me! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 17):

I had to close xcode and delete derived data. Just delete this folder

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

---

None of these approaches worked for me

1. `gem uninstall cocoapods`, `gem install cocoapods` and `pod install`
2. `pod install`
3. clean xcode using `cmd+k`

Answer (score 2):

This is the strange behaviour of Xcode.

FIXED SOLUTION:

0- Simulator: `Simulator` > `Reset Content & Settings`

1- Hold `alt` `Product` -> `Clean` Build Folder

2- Close Xcode

3- Go to project directory using terminal
`cd ~/projectDir`

4- Run `pod install`

5- Open project in Xcode

6- Run the project.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ gem uninstall cocoapods
$ gem install cocoapods
```

Add all things (crashlytics and fabric included) as pods.
Delete any extra things you made i.e. /Users/username/Documents/new_ios/ios-app/Pods/Headers/TPKeyboardAvoiding/TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.h

```
$ pod install
```

Comment: Did this work for anyone? Just tried it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

we have two options to resolve the issue

1. Delete the derived data from xcode's default location as specified in File -> Workspace Settings
2. Change the derived data location to a custom location in File -> Workspace Settings